# mysql join 3 tables by id

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables to join and need some help to make it work, this is my schema:

donations:

```
+--------------------+------------+   
|   uid   |  amount  |   date     |
+---------+----------+------------+
|    1    |    20    | 2013-10-10 | 
|    2    |    5     | 2013-10-03 | 
|    2    |    50    | 2013-09-25 |
|    2    |    5     | 2013-10-01 |
+---------+----------+------------+
```

users:

```
+----+------------+
| id |  username  | 
+----+------------+
| 1  |    rob     |
| 2  |    mike    | 
+----+------------+
```

causes:

```
+--------------------+------------+
|   id    |   uid    |   cause    | <missing cid (cause id)
+---------+----------+------------+
|    1    |    1     |  stop war  | 
|    2    |    2     |   love     | 
|    3    |    2     |   hate     | 
|    4    |    2     |   love     | 
+---------+----------+------------+
```

Result I want (data cropped for reading purposes)

```
+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|    id   |   username  | amount  |    cause    | 
+---------+-------------+---------+-------------+
|    1    |     rob     |   20    |  stop war   |
|    2    |     mike    |   5     |    love     |
+---------+-------------+-----------------------+
```

etc...

This is my current query, but returns double data:

```
SELECT i.*, t.cause as tag_name
FROM users i
INNER JOIN donations tti ON (tti.uid = i.id)
INNER JOIN causes t ON (t.uid = tti.uid)
```

EDIT: fixed sql schema on fiddle
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e06c/1 schema and data

How I can do this?

Comment: You know you have no direct relation between cause and donation?

Comment: yes, just updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your table's model is not right. There should be a relation between the Causes and Donations.

If not when you do your joins you will get duplicated rows.

For instance. Your model could look like this:

Donations

```
+--------------------+------------+
|   uid   |  amount  |   date     |  causeId
+---------+----------+------------+
|    1    |    20    | 2013-10-10 |     1
|    2    |    5     | 2013-10-03 |     2
|    2    |    50    | 2013-09-25 |     3
|    2    |    5     | 2013-10-01 |     2
+---------+----------+------------+
```

causes:

```
+----------------------+
|   id    |   cause    |
+---------+------------+
|    1    |   stop war | 
|    2    |   love     | 
|    3    |   hate     | 
+---------+------------+
```

And the right query then should be this

```
SELECT i.*, t.cause as tag_name
FROM users i
INNER JOIN donations tti ON (tti.uid = i.id)
INNER JOIN causes t ON (t.id = tti.causeId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT CONCAT(i.username ,' ',i.first_name) `name`, 
SUM(tti.amount), 
t.cause AS tag_name
FROM users i
LEFT JOIN donations tti ON (tti.uid = i.id)
INNER JOIN causes t ON (t.uid = tti.uid)
GROUP BY i.id
```

### [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0e06c/20)

Answer (score 0):

You need to match the id from both the users and causes table at the same time, like so:

```
SELECT i.*, t.cause as tag_name
FROM users i
INNER JOIN donations tti ON (tti.uid = i.id)
INNER JOIN causes t ON (t.uid = tti.uid and t.id = i.id)
```

Apologies for formatting, I'm typing this on a phone.